# Does Gowther go back to the 10 Commandments?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

When Gowther gets his memories back, does he turn back to the 10 Commandments or stay in the 7 Deadly Sins?

Answer (score 1):

The original Gowther created the doll, and died to end the holy war. Leaving something to take his place he created Gowther the doll. Gowther the doll joined the 7 deadly sins and went on adventuring with them to end the demons with the 10 commandments.

Gowther may have betrayed the 7 Deadly Sins a few times but he has not left the 7 deadly sins and still goes on trying to end the demons and prevent the holy war form happening again.

This based on what happens in season 3.